# Views.py not receiving POST data

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, html

I've been spending the past few hours trying to solve this problem to no avail. I have a form being filled with dynamically generated content in one of my django views:

```
<div class="list-group">                    
    {% for article in article_list %}           
            <a class="list-group-item" name="article" id="{{ article.id }}" onclick="getArticleData(this)">
            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"> {{ article.title }} </h4>
            <p class="list-group-item-text"> {{ article.content }} </p>
        </a>                        
    {% endfor %}                    
</div>
<form id="hiddenForm" method="post" action="/article/">
    <input id="hiddenInput" style="display:none" type="submit" name="articleData" value=""></input>
</form>
```

Each one of these elements is attached to an onclick() method in Javascript. This is used to determine which element was clicked from the dynamic list. The unique ID of the clicked value is set to the value of the hiddenInput, which is inside the hiddenForm. The form then gets submitted with this value.

```
function getArticleData(source)
{       
    $('#hiddenInput').attr('value', source.id); 
    $('#hiddenForm').submit();
}
```

This is the code in my python view in the corresponding function:

```
    if request.method == "POST":
        print('GOT POST')
        print(request.POST)
```

This is the output I am receiving - the post data is empty.

```
[27/Apr/2014 03:22:14] "POST /accounts/loggedin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2453
GOT POST
<QueryDict: {}>
```

Am I doing something wrong handling the form information being translated between the HTML and Django? I've also printed out the entire HTTP request and the POST data is still empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `display:none` is fine, that doesn't affect the form. The problem is with your HTML, from using an `input[type=submit]`: the form doesn't look at inputs with `type=submit`, even if they have a `name` attribute. Switch it to `type=number`, and it'll work.